# If S is shift operator, what is $P( (X_1,...,) \in S^{-n} (A_1 \times ... \times A_n \times .... )$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If S is shift operator $S(x_1,...) = (x_2,...)$, what is $$P( (X_1,..., X_n, ...) \in S^{-n} (A_1 \times ... \times  A_n \times  .... ))?$$

I don't understand what the inverse shift operator on an infinite product is.

And now I don't understand why i can't submit question, it keeps saying it's not up to standards. Now I am just writing hoping it finally is elligible for submission. What more can I say, I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Observe that $(x_N + 1, ..., X_N + k) \in A_1 \times ... \times A_k = S^N(X_1,...,X_k) \in A_1 \times ... \times A_k$. Thus this is equivalent to $(X_1,...,X_k) \in S^{-N}( A_1 \times ... \times A_k)$, which is what I wanted to know what was.